# How to disaggregate elements in groups?

Tags: python, pandas

I have N no. of elements with several attributes. The data frame looks like:

```
  Element_type Colour   Shape Texture  Total_No_of_elements_in_type
0            A    red    cube   rough                            12
1            B  green    cube  smooth                            23
2            C    red  sphere  smooth                             9
```

These N elements are grouped as follows:

```
Group   No_red  No_green    _   No_cube No_sphere   _   No_rough    No_smooth   _   Total_No_in_group

0   aa     6      11       _      21       3       _       8       12      _       34
1   bb    13       2       _       3       7       _       5       9       _       17
2   cc     5       2       _      15      21       _       7       23      _       49
```

Now, I want to find out possible No of type A in group aa, type B in group aa……so on.

Thanks,
Adnan

Comment: Can you add your expected output?

Comment: Is the `grouped ` dataframe made from the original `elements` dataframe? There is no way to "ungroup" it to find the data that was used to create the `grouped` dataframe if you do not have access to the data.

Comment: Please add the output you expect.

Comment: The expected output to be the no. of A-type elements, no of B-type elements….. in-group ‘aa’….. The grouped data is created form the same no of elements with the same attributes. Thanks.